# Provide Gnome online account

Tags: gnome, android, online-accounts

I am thinking about writing an Android-Gnome SMS utility. The cleanest way to do that seems to be by providing an online service that syncs with android and can be added as "online-account" in Gnome3.

However, I am gaining the impression that such online accounts are not intended to be added by third-party software in Gnome.

Is that correct? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: i find to need rebuild of gnome-online-accounts with module to provide new service. Did you know way to extend gnome-online-accounts by plugin or dbus?

Comment: Hey, I did not proceed with that project, so I have no experience to share. Sorry.